# Github actions workflow for an R package using reticulate and python dependencies

Tags: python, r, github-actions, reticulate, testthat

I'm trying to install `python` dependencies for automating unit testing within a `github` repository of an `R` package that uses [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) (specifically converting [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) objects to [`iGraph`](https://igraph.org/r/) `R` objects [via json](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/readwrite/json_graph.html)). I'm working from [`reticulate`'s `github-action`](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/master/.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml) and get stuck building within `linux` (`ubuntu` specifically), where it seems `conda` may be the safest way to install python dependencies.

```
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate r-reticulate
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

Error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘py2Rgraphs’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'py2Rgraphs', details:
  call: NULL
  error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3
Error: Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/runner/work/py2Rgraphs/py2Rgraphs/check/py2Rgraphs.Rcheck/py2Rgraphs’

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 1 note ✖
```

I'm also having issues with `macOS` and `windows` but wanted to start by fixing the `linux` builds.
As I understand it, it will be particularly difficult to enable tests that require `python` on `CRAN`, so at least automating that within the `git` repository seems a crucial prerequisite. I can at least confirm the tests pass fine locally and on some colleagues' computers.

Comment: Any success?  I'm having a related problem.   Can you share your Github repo URL?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yeah I'm a bit further so might need to close this and start afresh. https://github.com/griff-rees/py2Rgraphs/runs/2222979858?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've had some mixed success... I was overthinking a bit, it "just worked" on Ubuntu, but both Windows and Mac have different problems. I just turned those off for now! https://github.com/bryanhanson/readBrukerNMR